# Looking for a closed form for $a_m =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+m}{m}\frac{1}{4^{k}(2(k+m))!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have this sequence 
$$
a_m =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+m}{m}\frac{1}{4^{k}(2(k+m))!}
$$
and there seems to exist a patern arising when it is evaluated by WA. It involves $\cosh(1/2)$ and $\sinh(1/2)$. Bellow are the first 
$$
\begin{align*}
a_0 &=  \cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
a_1 &= \sinh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
a_2 &=  \frac{1}{2}\left(\cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right )-2\sinh\left(\frac{1}{2} \right )  \right )\\
&\vdots\\
\end{align*}
$$
but $\cosh(1/2)$ and $\sinh(1/2)$ keeps showing up for $a_3$, $a_4$, $\cdots$

Could anyone find a general expression for $a_m$ involving $\cosh(1/2)$ and $\sinh(1/2)$.

I'd apprecaite any help, thanks.

Comment: I looks very much as a Modified Bessel functions...

Comment: Did you make it? Try to write the Modified Bessel for $$\alpha = \frac{m-1}{2}$$ and $$x= \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson. Do you prefer I delete my answer ? I was typing when your last comment came. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, No, the sign is not correct.

Comment: nope. Better it's answered! You did very fine. (I upvoted you already!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_m = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(k+m)! 4^{-k}}{m! k! (2k+2m)!}=\frac{4^m}{m!}\cdot\left.\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(x/4)^{k+m}}{(2k+2m)!}\right|_{x=1} $$
and now you may recognize in the last series part of the Taylor series of $\cosh(\sqrt{x}/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

As Guilherme Thompson commented,
$$a_m =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+m}{m}\frac{a^k}{(2(k+m))!}=\sqrt{\pi }\frac{ 2^{-m-\frac{1}{2}} a^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{m}{2}} }{m!} I_{m-1/2}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)$$ where appears  the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

So, for $a=\frac 14$, this reduces to $$a_m=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 }\frac 1{m!}\,I_{m-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ which results, as you observed, in linear combinations of $\cosh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\sinh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Just to complement, (since I had typed already!),
$$
I_{\alpha }(x)=
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos (\alpha \theta ) e^{x \cos (\theta)} \, \mathrm{d} \theta
-\frac{\sin (\alpha \pi)}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty } e^{-\left[ t\alpha + x \cosh (t) \right]} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson. Good complement. Thanks.